# Adding an executable jar file in your java project in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I have an executable jar file that I want to run in my main method, should i put it on my project libraries? how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

right click on project ->Properites->Libraries -> Add jar/folder.

After create an instance of your class in main function.